# Tried to download openCV for python, but it keeps giving me this error

Tags: python, opencv

Collecting opencv-python
Using cached opencv-python-4.4.0.44.tar.gz (88.9 MB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: still running...
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Preparing wheel metadata: started
Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Processing c:\users\frede\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\a3\17\dd\f2dba23a35bb6008732772ccfb13d3d0e537fbc6919ce6862b\numpy-1.19.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517): started
Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build opencv-python

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\frede\Desktop\Call of Duty Modern Warfare\Autopilot_GTAV\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\frede\Desktop\Call of Duty Modern Warfare\Autopilot_GTAV\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0a24iz5l'
cwd: C:\Users\frede\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\opencv-python
Complete output (153 lines):

---

### -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator

---

---

---

---

---

### --
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/frede/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

---

---

---

---

---

---

### -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure

---

### -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141" generator

---

---

---

---

---

--
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
Generator

```
  Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/frede/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

---

---

---

---

---

---

### -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141" generator - failure

---

### -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator

---

---

---

---

---

--
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

```
  cl

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/frede/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/frede/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

---

---

---

---

---

---

### -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure

---

### -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator

---

---

---

---

---

--
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

```
  cl

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

To use the JOM generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/frede/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/frede/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

---

---

---

---

---

---

### -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure

---

scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

Building windows wheels for Python 3.9 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

```
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
```

---

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: More details and context would be required in order to answere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you need to either:

1. Download and install a C/C++ compiler on your machine (since you are on Windows, you may consider https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/), **OR**
2. Downgrade your python to 3.8 or older

In long:

As of right now (2020-10-19), `opencv` (as well as many other popular packages like `numpy`) don't have wheels for Python 3.9, so you have to build the wheels from source yourself.

Comment: Thank you for commenting so fast, extremely helpful. I was so lost haha, have a nice day.